# Is it possible to see how many local notications are scheduled?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Is there a way to see how many local notifications have been scheduled?

For a long time I was under the impression that this would be possible (and I already found some 3rd party tools for that too), but I can't find any examples of how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see which local notifications your app has scheduled using [`UNUserNotificationCenter getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649513-getpendingnotificationrequests)

There is an undocumented limit of 64 notifications that can be scheduled at once.